# Installing a bash-completion script

Tags: bash

I have a bash-completion script that I install as follows (on macOS with the MacPort version of bash-completion)

```
$ pkg-config --variable=completionsdir bash-completion
/opt/local/share/bash-completion/completions
$ sudo cp check_ssl_cert.completion /opt/local/share/bash-completion/completions/check_ssl_cert
```

The script is not loaded automatically (as all the others in the directory).

But is seems to work if sourced manually

```
$ complete -p check_ssl_cert
-bash: complete: check_ssl_cert: no completion specification
$ source /opt/local/share/bash-completion/completions/check_ssl_cert 
$ complete -p check_ssl_cert
complete -F _check_ssl_cert check_ssl_cert
```

Permissions and ownership are the same as all the other completion scripts.

E.g.:

```
$ ls -l /opt/local/share/bash-completion/completions/check*
-rw-r--r--  1 root  admin   374 Nov  3 03:22 /opt/local/share/bash-completion/completions/check_db
-rw-r--r--  1 root  admin   319 Nov  3 03:22 /opt/local/share/bash-completion/completions/check_perms
-rw-r--r--  1 root  admin  2708 Feb 17 21:29 /opt/local/share/bash-completion/completions/check_ssl_cert
-rw-r--r--  1 root  admin   746 Nov  3 03:22 /opt/local/share/bash-completion/completions/checksec
```

Any hint on what am I doing wrong?

Comment: I'm not on Mac, but I believe completion functions are loaded lazily, meaning that `compgen -p foo` will say there is no completion specification available until you invoke the completion of `foo` at least once.

Comment: @fra-san Yes also on Mac. All the others are loaded, mine no ...

Comment: What I meant is: if I type `complete -p sh` in a new interactive Bash instance I get a "no completion specification" message. Then, if I type `sh ` (note the trailing space) and then hit `<TAB>`, bash-completion loads the completion specification for `sh` and, after that, `complete -p sh` outputs `complete -F _sh sh`. If your completion spec is not loaded even after typing `check_ssl_cert ` and hitting `<TAB>`, then enabling tracing (`set -x`) in a new shell and looking at what happens when you type `check_ssl_cert ` + `<TAB>` in a new Bash instance may be of help.

Comment: @fra-san seems to work, thanks